# Why does this version mysqli result work?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The following code describes a substitute for the MySQL function mysql_result.  Since there is none in mysqli, I found the code that does the same exact thing, except it is just a user-created function.  The reason I am using the function is because I need to get data from different tables.

```
<?php 
 function mysqli_result($res, $row, $field=0) { 
 $res->data_seek($row); 
 $datarow = $res->fetch_array(); 
 return $datarow[$field]; 
} 
?>
```

The arguments are the same as mysql_result.br>
After reading about php functions, I am having a problem understanding:

- What is the difference between `$field=0` and `$field`
- I think I found something similar on object oriented statements, but does `$res->data_seek($row);` set `$res` equal to the data seek of `$row`?  Say `$row` is row one, would `$res` now only select row one of the tables selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read about [default function parameters in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/functions.arguments.php).
   If the caller does not supply a value for the third parameter (`$field`), it will be set to `0` by default.
2. Read about [OOP basis in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.basic.php).
   `$res->data_seek($row);` only calls a method called `data_seek` on the `res` object with one parameter, which is the object `row`. It depends on `data_seek()` whether the supplied object (objects are always passed by reference) will get modified.